# Laravel api error 405 method not allowed + POST method received as GET by the server

Tags: php, laravel, api

i'm facing an issue with my Laravel api.

All my POST requests are getting 405 error (method not allowed) and are received as GET request by the server in production environment only.
Everything works perfectly fine in dev and local environment.

I'm developing with the version 5.8.* of Laravel on an nginx server.

Here is an example with my root for login:

```
Route::post('/login', 'Api\PassportController@login');
```

can someone help please ?

Comment: you need to turn one your debugger then u can see details

Comment: I'm just getting a 405 error telling me I'm trying to access the url with a Get method, which is not allowed. 
I do not understand how my POST request is received as a GET request by the server